# HTML Lexical Analyzer using Java

Tags: java, html, lexical-analysis

I'm a student programmer and i'm trying to build a lexical analyzer for HTML code for one of my computer science classes where the output should be the individual tokens and lexemes of the HTML code. But when I compile and run my analyzer, there seems to be something wrong with the output.

Given following the HTML code:

```
    <table>
    <tr><td>temp</td><td>temp2</td></tr>
    </table>
```

The output should be:

```
    TOKEN       LEXEME
    ------------------
    TAGIDENT    <table
    GTHAN       >
    TAGIDENT    <tr
    GTHAN       >
    TAGIDENT    <td
    GTHAN       >
    IDENT       temp
    ENDTAGHEAD  </
    IDENT       td
    GTHAN       >
    TAGIDENT    <td
    GTHAN       >
    IDENT       temp2
    ENDTAGHEAD  </
    IDENT       td
    GTHAN       >
    ENDTAGHEAD  </
    IDENT       tr
    GTHAN       >
```

Currently, this is the code I have:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class LexAnalyzer {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try { 
        String input = "" , s = "";
        Token t;
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new        File("Sample.html")));
        while((s = in.readLine()) != null) {
            input += s;
        }
        System.out.println(input);
        System.out.println("TOKEN       LEXEME");
        System.out.println("------------------");
        ArrayList<Token> a = getToken(input);
        for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(a.get(i).getId() + "    " + a.get(i).getLexeme());
        }
    }

    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static ArrayList<Token> getToken(String input) {
    String lexeme = ""; //lexeme = TOKEN = ie. TAGIDENT
    Token t = null;
    ArrayList<Token> a = new ArrayList<Token>();
    for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        if(input.charAt(i) == '<') {
            lexeme += input.charAt(i); 
            i++;
            //case 1: if followed by ! < = COMMENT
            if(input.charAt(i) == '!') {
                lexeme += input.charAt(i);
                i++;
                while(input.charAt(i) != '>') {
                    lexeme += input.charAt(i);
                    i++;
                }
                input = input.substring(lexeme.length(), input.length());
            }

            //case 2: if followed by letter < = TAGIDENT
            else if(isALetter(input.charAt(i))) {
                lexeme += input.charAt(i);
                i++;
                while(input.charAt(i) != '>' && input.charAt(i) != ' ') {
                    lexeme += input.charAt(i);
                    i++;
                }
                t = new Token("TAGIDENT", lexeme);
                input = input.substring(lexeme.length(), input.length());
                a.add(t);
            }

            //case 3: if followed by number or space < = LTHAN
            else if((isANumber(input.charAt(i)))) {
                lexeme += input.charAt(i);
                i++;
                while(input.charAt(i) != '<' || input.charAt(i) == ' ') { 
                    lexeme += input.charAt(i);
                    i++;
                }
                t = new Token("LTHAN", lexeme);
                input = input.substring(lexeme.length(), input.length());
                a.add(t);
            }

            //case 4: if followed by / < = ENDTAGHEAD
            else if(input.charAt(i) == '/') {
                lexeme += input.charAt(i);
                i++;
                //case 5: after ENDTAGHEAD -> IDENT
                if(isALetter(input.charAt(i))) {
                    lexeme += input.charAt(i);
                    i++;
                    while(input.charAt(i) != '>') {
                        lexeme += input.charAt(i);
                        i++;
                    }
                    t = new Token("IDENT", lexeme);
                    input = input.substring(lexeme.length(), input.length());
                    a.add(t);
                }
                t = new Token("ENDTAGHEAD", lexeme);
                input = input.substring(lexeme.length(), input.length());
                a.add(t);
            }
        }

        else if(input.charAt(i) == '>') {
            lexeme += input.charAt(i);
            i++;
            t = new Token("GTHAN", lexeme);
            input = input.substring(lexeme.length(), input.length());
        }
    }
    return a;
}

public static boolean isALetter(char inputChar) {
    Boolean itIsALetter = false;
    if("qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM".indexOf(inputChar) != -1) {
        itIsALetter = true;
    }
    return itIsALetter;
}

public static boolean isANumber(char inputChar) {
    Boolean itIsANumber = false;
    if("1234567890".indexOf(inputChar) != -1) {
        itIsANumber = true;
    }
    return itIsANumber;
}
```

}

Token class:

```
public class Token {
    String id, lexeme;

    public Token(String id, String lexeme) {
        this.id = id;
        this.lexeme = lexeme;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getLexeme() {
        return lexeme;
    }
}
```

The output from my code:

```
    TOKEN       LEXEME
    ------------------
    TAGIDENT    <table
    IDENT       <table>></td
    ENDTAGHEAD  <table>></td
```

Any advice on how to fix my code? Thanks so much!

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: What does your `Token` class look like?

Comment: My Token class just contains the following:

public class Token {
 String id, lexeme;
 public Token(String id, String lexeme) {
  this.id = id;
  this.lexeme = lexeme;
 }
 
 public String getId() {
  return id;
 }
 
 public String getLexeme() {
  return lexeme;
 }
}

Comment: @ElliotFrisch I haven't used a debugger before you think it'll be useful for my problem?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you read a token:

```
while(input.charAt(i) != '>' && input.charAt(i) != ' ') {
    lexeme += input.charAt(i);
    i++;
}
```

you should add one more line right after the while loop:

```
lexeme += input.charAt(i);
```

in order to read the last closing char `>`. Once you'll fix all these places in the code (or better yet, refactor your code and extract it to an external helper method) - you'll get the complete token/s.

Answer (score 1):

You are not fully iterating over the contents of your `input String`, as you are taking `substrings`, incrementing counter `i` and checking for your `input length`.

In fact you don't have to take substring at all as per your code `lexeme` takes care of getting the required content. However, `lexeme` also adds data to itself and per your print statements you want individual elements to be displayed as part of your `lexeme`.

**Remove this:**

```
input = input.substring(lexeme.length(), input.length());
```

At the start of every parent condition, instead of incrementing `lexeme`, **start it from the beginning**

```
lexeme = "" + input.charAt(i);
```

However, in your inner loops and conditions, you might still want to increment it.

Another aspect is you have not written the code to handle the `text` content (`temp`).

**EDIT:**

Based on the above suggestions, I tried your code with the changed XML and here is the changed `getToken()`:

```
public static ArrayList<Token> getToken(String input) {
        String lexeme = ""; // lexeme = TOKEN = ie. TAGIDENT
        Token t = null;
        ArrayList<Token> a = new ArrayList<Token>();

        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
            if (input.charAt(i) == '<') {
                lexeme = "" + input.charAt(i);
                i++;
                // case 1: if followed by ! < = COMMENT
                if (input.charAt(i) == '!') {
                    lexeme += input.charAt(i);
                    i++;
                    while (input.charAt(i) != '>') {
                        lexeme += input.charAt(i);
                        i++;
                    }

                }

                // case 2: if followed by letter < = TAGIDENT
                if (isALetter(input.charAt(i))) {
                    lexeme += input.charAt(i);
                    i++;
                    while (input.charAt(i) != '>' && input.charAt(i) != ' ') {
                        lexeme += input.charAt(i);
                        i++;
                    }
                    t = new Token("TAGIDENT", lexeme);

                    a.add(t);
                }

                // case 3: if followed by number or space < = LTHAN
                if ((isANumber(input.charAt(i)))) {
                    lexeme = "" + input.charAt(i);
                    i++;
                    while (input.charAt(i) != '<' || input.charAt(i) == ' ') {
                        lexeme += input.charAt(i);
                        i++;
                    }
                    t = new Token("LTHAN", lexeme);

                    a.add(t);
                }

                // case 4: if followed by / < = ENDTAGHEAD
                if (input.charAt(i) == '/') {
                    lexeme = "" + input.charAt(i);
                    i++;
                    // case 5: after ENDTAGHEAD -> IDENT
                    if (isALetter(input.charAt(i))) {
                        lexeme += input.charAt(i);
                        i++;
                        while (input.charAt(i) != '>') {
                            lexeme += input.charAt(i);
                            i++;
                        }
                        t = new Token("IDENT", lexeme);

                        a.add(t);
                    }
                    t = new Token("ENDTAGHEAD", lexeme);

                    a.add(t);
                }

                if (input.charAt(i) == '>') {
                    lexeme = "" + input.charAt(i);
                    // i++;
                    t = new Token("GTHAN", lexeme);

                    a.add(t);
                }

            }

            else if (input.charAt(i) == '>') {
                lexeme = "" + input.charAt(i);
                i++;
                t = new Token("GTHAN", lexeme);

                a.add(t);
            }
            // System.out.println(temp);
        }
        return a;
    }
```

**Output** I get is:

```
TOKEN       LEXEME
------------------
TAGIDENT    <table
GTHAN    >
TAGIDENT    ><tr
GTHAN    >
TAGIDENT    ><td
GTHAN    >
IDENT    /td
ENDTAGHEAD    /td
GTHAN    >
TAGIDENT    ><td
GTHAN    >
IDENT    /td
ENDTAGHEAD    /td
GTHAN    >
IDENT    /tr
ENDTAGHEAD    /tr
GTHAN    >
IDENT    /table
ENDTAGHEAD    /table
GTHAN    >
```

Not the exact output but still gets you all the elements and should get you going.

Comment: Alright! Will try this out as well! Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Everything works out fine except when I try to handle non-tags such as "temp". I use this conditional statement to handle non-tags but the program then ends up with an OutOfBoundsException. CODE:

    
else if (isALetter(input.charAt(i))) {
    lexeme = "" + input.charAt(i);
    i++;
    while(input.charAt(i) != '<') {     //OUTOFBOUNDSEXCEPTION: 53
     lexeme += input.charAt(i);
     i++;
    }
    t = new Token("IDENT", lexeme);
    a.add(t);
   }

Comment: @user3262031 that's because you use the up the entire length of the String within the first if statement `if (input.charAt(i) == '<') {`. It's actually within this if itself the whole HTML is traversed since it starts with this tag itself. Try placing your code within this if somewhere, you shouldn't get the error